# Error with Apache Spark Installation

Tags: apache-spark

I tried to install Apache Spark through guidance from this video: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KvQto_b3sqw`

However, I got all these errors (attached in the screenshots) which the video did not show:

[Error Screenshot Part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zu4XP.jpg)

[Error Screenshot Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lQ6B.jpg)

I would like to know whether I did install Apache Spark successfully? What can I do to ensure that I install Apache Spark successfully?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

In order to install spark, you should install Java and Scala

Download Scala from

https://www.scala-lang.org/download/

Untar the file

sudo tar -zxvf tar file name

set the Scala path in /etc/environment

save and exit

source the /etc/environment

step 1: go your local path address where should you want to download the 
        tar file download the Spark from

```
    http://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-2.0.2/spark-2.0.2-bin-
    hadoop2.7.tgz
```

step 2: Untar the file with the command: sudo tar -zxvf tar file name

step 3:
        set the environment path in sudo nano /etc/environment

```
    /usr/local/packages/spark/bin:/usr/local/packages/spark/sbin"

    SPARK_HOME="/usr/local/packages/spark"
    SPARK_CONF_DIR="/usr/local/packages/spark/conf"
```

use commands:

1. ctrl x
2. Y
3. enter

   ```
   save and exit from /etc/environment
   ```

step 4: give source command through terminal: source /etc/environment

step 5: Download the MySQL connector java file from

```
    http://central.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.35/mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar
```

step 6: move the file into /usr/local/packages/spark/jars

step 7: Go to conf directory
        change the spark-env.sh.template to spark-env.sh

```
    mv spark-env.sh.template spark-env.sh
```

step 8: open the spark-env.sh file and change the modifications in file

```
    sudo nano spark-env.sh
```

export JAVA_HOME="$JAVA_HOME"

export SPARK_LOCAL_IP=127.0.1.1

export SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT=8088

export SPARK_HOME="/usr/local/packages/spark"

export SPARK_CLASSPATH="/usr/local/packages/spark/jars/mysql-connector-Java-5.1.35.bin.Jar"

( Make sure if you are installing the Spark without Hadoop then follow above configurations in spark-env.sh file )

( with Hadoop you should add 
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR="/usr/local/packages/hadop/etc/hadoop"  )

step 9: now go to sbin path in spark use the command: start-all.sh

it definitely works. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sth is wrong with our installation. 
How to Install:

1. Download spark from http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html
2. Untar file
3. run spark-shell script in SPARK_HOME/bin directory

spark-shell should run without error.

Comment: See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10528.  You must put winutils into the bin directory and set HADOOP_HOME to point to the Spark directory.

Comment: https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WindowsProblems

Download and copy winutils.exe to your SPARK_HOME\bin folder. Re-run spark-shell